# Regular Expression in Redshift running PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table in redshift running PostgreSQL in which one of the columns is url.

I need to extract parameters from this url.

ie. if url=foo.bar?param1=a&param2=b&param1=c

I need the value of param1 which is c from this url

Tried a few solutions like

```
(string_to_array(url,'param1='))[array_upper(string_to_array(url,'param1='),1)]
```

and

```
regexp_matches
```

Redshift does not allow arrays, so both methods are useless.
Is there a way to solve this using SQL ?

Comment: I think you need a regex like `param1=([^&=\s]+)(?!.*param1)` ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `regexp_matches` like this:

```
SELECT regexp_matches('url=foo.bar?param1=a&param2=b&param1=c', E'param1=([^&=\s]+)(?!.*param1)');
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/3681)